# How can I change default tick values on a d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to customize the ticks on my graph's Y axis. I have the ff code:

```
    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
          .attr("fill", "#000")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", "0.71em")
          .attr("dx", "-2em")
          .attr("font-size", "15px")
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(unitOfMeasure[0]);
```

I'm not so sure how to make it so that each value being generated for the chart creates its own tick value? And not just 0,5,10,15,20 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to give a precise answer, as you did not specify the exact requirements for the ticks of your y-axis.

However, a general solution would be to make use of the following 2 methods, as specified by the [d3.js axes documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#d3-axis), [axis.ticks()](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_ticks), and optionally, [axis.tickFormat()](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickFormat).

Assuming we are inputting the following data into the y-axis,

```
const yValues = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40];
```

First, we will need to generate a scale for your axis. We set the domain of the scale with the minimum and maximum value from the array defined above.

```
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([d3.min(yValues), d3.max(yValues)])
  .range([0, height]);
```

Next, we set the scale and return the axis.

```
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale);
```

As you can see, we did not use the `axis.ticks()`, or `axis.tickFormat()`, and this will result in the default y-axis format, specified by your scale. This will result in the following below, which is probably similar to what you are having.

```js
const margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const yValues = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40];

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([d3.min(yValues), d3.max(yValues)])
  .range([0, height]);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)

const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
.axis path,
line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, since you want the ticks to be customised, we will need to make use of `axis.ticks()`. For instance, if you want to set the intervals between each tick in the axis such that it is in multiples of 1's (1,2,3,4,5,etc) instead of multiples of 5's (5, 10, 15, etc), you can simply supply the `axis.ticks()` with an argument to generate the required tick interval.

```
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .ticks(d3.max(yValues) - d3.min(yValues));
```

If you want to take this further, you can even format the ticks by using `axis.tickFormat()`. For instance, if you want to supply the axis to be displayed in decimal format,

```
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
```

By piecing above together, this is what you will see:

```js
const margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const yValues = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40];

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([d3.min(yValues), d3.max(yValues)])
  .range([0, height]);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .ticks(d3.max(yValues) - d3.min(yValues))
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'))

const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
.axis path,
line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gah thank you for this! I tried to add axis.ticks but nothing seems to be working. I've uploaded my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uhmr40qc/) . Do you mind doing a check please? Getting really frustrated already huhu @wentjun

Comment: @Angela could you try to reproduce it with sample data, so that I can run it on jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1):

As an example from https://github.com/d3/d3-axis

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickValues([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]);
```

there is a tickValues to define ticks explicitly